# ID of root folder does not match parent ID of items in it

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am listing all files in a users drive using the files.list method without the q parameter. Now i want to be able to reconstruct the hierarchy of my drive in my code.

I thought it should be easy enough to to just compare the ID of the root with the parent ids of my files.

I got the Id of my root folder with files.get:

```
dservice.Files.Get("root").Execute().Id;
```

The returned Id does not exactly match any of the Ids my files have as parents  so i tried the other way around and tried to query the parents Id via files.get.

The returned IDs match partly but are not identical 0AEH_mZWZV8V5Uk9PVA (via file.get) vs 0ABnBk49dSTN5Uk9PVA (in parent property)

For all files that reside in my root folder i get a file not found error when i try to get the parent via the Id in parents.

It might be worth mentioning that the user/drive are part of a gsuite domain and are accessed through a service account.

So how can i find out which of my listed files are in the root of the drive without having to rely on the idea that any file whose parent id returns an error is in the root?

Comment: I think that the method for retrieving the root folder ID like your script is good. As other workaround, although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, for example, how about checking the length of folder ID? In my environment, the length of root folder ID is 19. The lengths of folder IDs except for the root folder are 28 and 33. For example, it's `if (lengthOfID === 19) {do something} else {do something}`. In this case, these results are the same between the service account drive and own drive. If this is not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike interesting observation, do you know if the length of those ids is defined somewhere? I don´t want to rely on arbitrary properties. For the moment i´ve switched to listing shared files separately and using q="'root' in parents" to loop myself from the root downwards. Its reliable but not as elegant as just comparing IDs

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I have never seen the official document about the length of ID. But, for example, at Google Docs and Google Apps Script project, the lengths of file IDs are 57 and 44, respectively. It seems that this is the constant now. And also, in my experience, at Google Drive, I think that the length of root folder ID is the shortest in all folder IDs in the Google Drive. So I proposed this. But I apologize that my proposal is not included in the official document.

Comment: Hello @Paul, are you getting different ids even if you are trying the Drive API [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)? Cheers!